# Add to xml stored in sql 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, insert

I have a SQL Server 2005 database which has a table called improvements.

Within Improvements is a field called TransactionID and one called Comments.  The field Comments is a XML data type with such entries as follows.

```
<Comment>
    <CreatedBy>Bob</CreatedBy>
    <CreatedDateTime>2009-08-24T11:36:13.020774+01:00</CreatedDateTime>
    <CreaterRole>Manager</CreaterRole>
    <CreationStage>INITIAL REVIEW</CreationStage>
    <CreationStatus>APPROVED</CreationStatus>
    <UserComment>Approved</UserComment>
</Comment>
<Comment>
    <CreatedBy>Bob</CreatedBy>
    <CreatedDateTime>2009-08-24T11:36:25.7240616+01:00</CreatedDateTime>
    <CreaterRole>Manager</CreaterRole>
    <CreationStage>CAPTURE</CreationStage>
    <CreationStatus>ACCEPTED</CreationStatus>
    <UserComment />
</Comment>
```

I need to enter an additional entry along the lines of:

```
 <Comment>
    <CreatedBy>Bob</CreatedBy>
    <CreatedDateTime>2013-01-29T11:36:25.7240616+01:00</CreatedDateTime>
    <CreaterRole>Manager</CreaterRole>
    <CreationStage>CLOSED</CreationStage>
    <CreationStatus>CLOSED</CreationStatus>
    <UserComment>Closed as agreed<UserComment />
 </Comment>
```

Where the TransactionID = *A transaction number.*

I have found a number of solutions on the internet to amend an entry using SET..... but cannot figure out how to actually add an entry.

Can anyone help me with this one please?

Many thanks in advance.

Kev.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
declare @TransactionID int
declare @Comment xml

set @TransactionID = 1
set @Comment = '
<Comment>
    <CreatedBy>Bob</CreatedBy>
    <CreatedDateTime>2013-01-29T11:36:25.7240616+01:00</CreatedDateTime>
    <CreaterRole>Manager</CreaterRole>
    <CreationStage>CLOSED</CreationStage>
    <CreationStatus>CLOSED</CreationStatus>
    <UserComment>Closed as agreed</UserComment>
</Comment>'

update improvements 
set Comments.modify('insert sql:variable("@Comment") as last into /')
where TransactionID = @TransactionID
```